# How to get testNG method name at runtime with the help of Java?

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I wonder if it's possible to grab the java method name in runtime?
I've tried this code already:

```
String name = new Object(){}.getClass().getEnclosingMethod().getName();
```

But it returns the last java method I ran, and I need to get the `@Test someTest() {} method name`

Comment: Did you see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2952202/how-do-i-get-the-name-of-the-test-method-that-was-run-in-a-testng-tear-down-meth

Comment: Yes, I did. I saw it. But this will work only if you want to get the method name after the test is completed (teardown). In my case, I would need to know how to get it during test execution in runtime.

Comment: You want to get the current method name which is running at testing, right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: And this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14921880/is-it-a-way-to-get-the-test-method-name-within-testng-listeners-on-configuration

Comment: Do you have  `methodName = new Object() {}.getClass().getEnclosingMethod().getName();` as first line one code in your @Test method?